# Is there a way to turn on assembly binding logging for a single web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

I want to troubleshoot an assembly binding issue, in a web application hosted in a shared development server, with the Assembly binding logging feature.

I don't want to enable it via the registry, because it will slowdown every other .NET application in the server. Is there a way to turn it on only for my web application, like, by adding something to my web.config?

Comment: Side note: A shared development server rarely is a good idea.